Rational homology sphere has the same cohomology ring as sphere
Let $M$ be a closed, $n$-dimensional manifold such that $H_0(M;\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q} = H_n(M;\mathbb{Q})$ and $H_i(M;\mathbb{Q}) =0$ for all $1 \le i \le n-1$. Then $M$ is a rational homology manifold.
Is it always true that the rational cohomology ring of $M$ is exactly the same as the rational cohomology ring of the $n$-sphere $S^n$, i.e., it is true that $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ for a generator $x \in H^n(M;\mathbb{Q})$ with the same cup-products?
I believe this is true: since there are no non-zero rational cohomology groups in the middle dimensions for $M$, one can proceed like in this answer to show that it is $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ with the same cup-products relations. But I just wanted to make sure I'm understanding it right because in general, the same (co)homology groups do not imply the same cohomology rings. Can someone verify that in the case of rational homology sphere $M$ though, the rational cohomology ring is the same as that of $S^n$? Thanks.

The rational cohomology is isomorphic as a vector space, and there are no possible nontrivial cup products, so yes.

They are the same, simply because there's no room for any non-trivial cup-products: Multiplication with elements of $H^0(M; \mathbb{Q})$ is just multiplying by scalars, and multiplying elements of $H^n(M; \mathbb{Q})$ together yields an element of $H^{2n}(M; \mathbb{Q}) = 0$.
